# Search for folder names higher than X with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

**I need to get all folders with a name higher than `1.0.0` with node.js**

How can i achieve this with the structure below.

```
|---version
    |--1.0.0
    |--1.2.0
    |--0.9.0
```

Thanks, am very new to node.

Comment: so.. what you done so far ? nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the directories have a name that are a valid semver string (like yours) the easiest way is to use the [semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) module and use the `gt` function. Something like this:

```
var greater = function (dir, cb){
    var max = null;
    fs.readdir (dir, function (error, entries){
        if (error) return cb (error);
        if (!entries.length) return cb ();
        entries.forEach (function (entry){
            //Suppose there're no files in the directory
            if (!max) return max = entry;
            if (semver.gt (entry, max)) max = entry;
        });
        cb (null, max)
    });
};

greater ("dir", function (error, dir){
    if (error) return handleError (error);
    if (dir){
        //dir is the greater
    }else{
        //No directories
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a synchronous version:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var regex = /^[1-9]\.\d\.\d/;

var folder = __dirname + "/version/";

var files = fs.readdirSync(folder).filter(function(file){

   return regex.test(file) && 
          fs.statSync(folder + file).isDirectory();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised @Gabriels dynamic answer to suit.
 Ended up needing a synchronous solution, inserted before my grunt init. **Here is the final code**, finding and returning the name of the latest folder version.

```
var getLatest = function (cwd) {
    var max = false;
    var dirs = fs.readdirSync(cwd);

    if (!dirs.length) {
        //No directories
    } else {
        dirs.forEach(function (dir) {
            if (!max) {
                return max = dir;
            }
            if (semver.gt(dir, max)) {
                max = dir;
            }
        });
    }
    return max;
};
```

`getLatest('build/');`